# Improving auto-generated messages (possible duplicate) to enhance new-user experience

Tags: feature-request

I learned on the Meta Stack Exchange that auto-generated blurbs can be adjusted by moderator request if enough users feel the change would be helpful.  I would suggest something like the following blurb as a gentler way to inform new users that they may have asked a duplicate question, giving them an opportunity to edit it or defend it before it gets closed.

> This question has been marked as a possible duplicate. Please edit
> your question or explain how it differs from those already asked or it
> could be closed based on votes by the community.  Does this answer
> your question? (link to similar question)

I think we should help people have as positive an experience as possible as they learn to navigate the site, because it will increase the likelihood that will stick around. If you agree with this and believe the change would be helpful, please vote this up or feel free to make other suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean for the comment that is posted automatically when flagging a duplicate, or as some other notice?

Comment: @curiousdannii I was referring to the duplicate auto comment here, but other comments might also be improved. "This question is off-topic" is pretty curt and vague.